# External link focusing on Cell

Tags: draw.io

I am using Drawio cloud service.

I would like to be able to generate an external link that when clicked would open a drawio graph, select the correct page and then **focus on a particular cell**

I can get a link that will select the correct page example : https://app.diagrams.net/#GRAPHID#%7B%22pageId%22%3A%22PAGEID%22%7D

Is there a parameter after the pageID that I missed that would focus on a cell by its id ?
I thought the Custom Links would offer some solution but it seems to be working only within a graph file itself, I need an external link.

Thanks